# How do C# interfaces hide public properties (eg. QBFC's ICustomerRet)?

Tags: c#, reflection, qbfc

I am experimenting with the QuickBooks Foundation Classes (QBFC) but find that only some of its interfaces' properties are available. For example:

```
Type myType = typeof(ICustomerRet);
foreach( PropertyInfo info in myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty) )
{
    Console.WriteLine( info.ToString() );
}
```

This prints:

```
QBFC13Lib.IQBIDType ListID 
QBFC13Lib.IQBStringType EditSequence 
QBFC13Lib.IQBStringType CompanyName 
QBFC13Lib.IQBStringType AccountNumber
```

However the interface, itself, has many more properties:

```
 [Guid("DF330518-953C-4813-BAEC-F65DDBBFEB5B")]
    [TypeLibType(4160)]
    public interface ICustomerRet : IQBBase
    {
        [DispId(47)]
        IQBStringType AccountNumber { get; }
        [DispId(36)]
        IQBBaseRefList AdditionalContactRefList { get; }
        [DispId(58)]
        IAdditionalNotesRetList AdditionalNotesRetList { get; }
        [DispId(35)]
        IQBStringType AltContact { get; }
        [DispId(30)]
        IQBStringType AltPhone { get; }
        ...
```

If I create my own version of the interface (ICustomerRet2) with just a copy & paste of the original then the code shows all of ICustomerRet2's properties.

What am I missing?

Comment: Anyone? Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: It appears to be a COM class, COM and reflection don't mix well.

Comment: Try adding `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`.  It's posible that the interface "inherits" the other methods from the base interface `IQBBase`